# Java: Simple If Statement not executing

Tags: java, mysql, concurrency

Alright, so this has been pissing me off for hours .I do not understand why isn't this if statement not executing. Here's my complete code. There are 2 classes, 'Client' is the main class and the other is the connector class.

```
package com.app.client;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Client{

    private int IntervalForDatabase=60000;
    private int IntervalForIPCheck=180000;
    private boolean AppRunning=true;
    public boolean ConnectionSuccess=false;
    private Connector ConnectionTools = new Connector();

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Client client = new Client();
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    Client(){
        /* Check For Current Instance Of Program */
        try{
            ServerSocket ApplicationSocket = new ServerSocket(6251);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.exit(0);
        }

         Thread Network = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                while(!ConnectionSuccess){
                    try{
                        ConnectionTools.ConnectToDatabaseServer();
                        ConnectionSuccess=true;
                        System.out.println("bein a bit");
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Network.start();

        Thread LiveConnectionCheck = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                while(AppRunning){
                    if(ConnectionSuccess){
                     /* THIS IF STATEMENT IS NOT EXECUTING */
                        try {
                            System.out.println("tester");
                            Thread.sleep(IntervalForIPCheck);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }           
        });

        LiveConnectionCheck.start();
    }
}
```

The connector class:

```
package com.app.client;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Connector {
    public boolean DatabaseConnection=false;
    Socket ClientSocket;
    private String DatabaseHost="localhost";
    private String DatabaseUsername="root";
    private String DatabasePassword = "";
    private String DatabaseName = "spyware";
    private String TableName="activespywares";
    public String CurrentServerIP = "";
    private Connection MYSQLConnection = null;
    public ResultSet result;

    public void ConnectToDatabaseServer(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            MYSQLConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+DatabaseHost+"/"+DatabaseName,DatabaseUsername,DatabasePassword);
            DatabaseConnection=true;            
            System.out.println("connected");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            DatabaseConnection=false;
            return;
        }
    }

    public String ObtainServerIP() throws SQLException{
        String text = "";           
        try{
            System.out.println("we've made it till here");
            PreparedStatement state = MYSQLConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `activespywares`");
            result = state.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("we've made it till here");
            if(result.next()){
                result.next();
                text = result.getString("InternetProtocol");
            }
            return text;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            text=e+"";
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

I've checked everything. I don't know what is the problem over here. The if statement is in the 'Client' Class. The connector class is just so you know that it's isn't causing problems.

Comment: why static?. static doesn't work.

Comment: I'd recommend you to use Java naming conventions for your variable names.

Comment: I would guess there is a race condition here? Maybe ```ConnectionSuccess``` is never set to true? Also, try debugging the program, see what the value of ```ConnectionSuccess``` during execution is..

Comment: Try and toss out as much of the code that's irrelevant to the problem. Then we will be in a better position to help you and perhaps you, yourself, will already find the issue while doing so. This is too much code.

Comment: Yes, I agree, java naming conventions are: variables start with lowercase letters and classes start with uppercase letters. Notice how stackoverflow is highlighting your variable names, it thinks they are types because they are capitalized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `connectionSuccess` either `volatile` or change to an `AtomicBoolean` (and mark as `final`). The problem is that you are setting the variable in one `Thread` but reading it from another.

Comment: what does volatile do? and What's an AtomicBoolean?

Comment: @Talha Tanveer volatile prevents cacheing of variable for a thread.Which vm do in order to optimize code

Comment: @TalhaTanveer it sounds like you need to do some research on concurrent programming in java before attempting to work with a concurrent application. I would strong suggest Java Concurrency in Practice. http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: The Client code is now running an infinite loop of checks for the other to turn a boolean to true. Use a Lock or so instead so it can wait for this to happen without consuming resources.

Answer (score 1):

```
        if(result.next()){
            result.next();
```

Make no sense. You are throwing the first result away when you call result.next() twice here.

Comment: I know, I want to ignore the first row. But that's not the main problem, I've even added a System Print statement but doesn't print out anything

Comment: Ok but odd. But you might want to also add an if to the second call to next() just in case the result only contains one row :}

Answer (score 1):

For your exceptions, I would recommend the usage of

```
 e.printStackTace()
```

in the case of something breaking your program.

Now if you execute

```
    //...your code
    if(result.next()){
        result.next();
    //...your code
```

It throws away your first result and presents you with your second result. I would recommend that you use

```
    //...your code
    while(result.next()){

    //...your code
```

to scroll through your records as you please

Comment: That's really not my question :P Read the second answer below, another guy already said that. I've made some changes. What's wrong with just printing out "e" ?

Comment: @TalhaTanveer Some of your exceptions go unhandled. Add it for the purpose of debugging.